# Python package repositories on CentOS/Ubuntu

Tags: python, centos, package, repository, quart

I'm wondering how does it work with python package repositories for CentOS (and also other distributions) as I can't find any article about that. Where do python packages/version come from?

My question comes from fact that I want to install python package Quart, and it offers only 2-years old package version 0.6.15 on both CentOS 7 and 8, while on Ubuntu it offers latest 0.14.1.

Answer (score 1):

The Quart 0.6.* releases are the last ones to support Python 3.6. If you install Python 3.7+ you can then install the latest Quart versions.

Comment: So does that mean that all linux distributions point to the same PyPi package source, but package versions are limited by python versions only?

Comment: Yes, there is a `python_version` marker on PyPI packages that controls this.